# Improve RESTful response time

Tags: database, rest, jakarta-ee, cxf, apache-tomee

I'm implementing a RESTful Service in Java EE with TomEE+(Apache CXF) which is using a database(specifically postgres). Now I've noticed that the longest time in my functions is spent in the getConnection() call for the database.

my code looks like this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {

    /* external DB resource
     * configured in the resources.xml as "testDB". Either match the
     * name or use the name parameter of the resource annotation.
     */
    @Resource private DataSource testDB;

    @Path("/hello")
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String test() throws SQLException
    {
        Connection conn = testDB.getConnection(); //majority of time is spent in here
    /*
      do something.(e.g. PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(...)
    */

        conn.close();
        return "world";
    }
}
```

The database is defined in a resources.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <Resource id="testDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed = false
    connectionProperties = 
    defaultAutoCommit = true
    defaultReadOnly = 
    definition = 
    ignoreDefaultValues = false
    initialSize = 0
    jdbcDriver = org.postgresql.Driver
    jdbcUrl = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb
    jtaManaged = true
    maxActive = 100
    maxIdle = 20
    maxOpenPreparedStatements = 0
    maxWaitTime = 100 millisecond
    minEvictableIdleTime = 30 minutes
    minIdle = 0
    numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
    password = password
    passwordCipher = PlainText
    poolPreparedStatements = false
    serviceId = 
    testOnBorrow = true
    testOnReturn = false
    testWhileIdle = false
    timeBetweenEvictionRuns = -1 millisecond
    userName = user
    validationQuery = SELECT 1;
    removeAbandoned = true
    removeAbandonedTimeout = 60
    logAbandoned = true

</Resource>
</resources>
```

So how could I reduce the time it takes to get a database connection? I'm already using the connection pooling mechanism. The only solution that comes to my mind is to make the resource class a singleton and get the connection once, but that seems counter-intuitive when many requests need to be worked on.

Comment: Was your observation made for a large number of requests? If the profiling conclusion was made for only one (especially first) request, it's kinda meaningless for a multitude of factors.

Comment: I repeated the test a few times. The times were varying but overall the getConnection call always takes the majority of time.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally expect the interaction with the database to be the slowest part of the process.  I would be interested in knowing how much overhead the database call is adding?  How is that in relation to making the database call via a SQL tool outside of the Java code.

Also - I'm not sure if the example is just for brevity, but I would try to layer your solution so that the initial layer handles routing and validation, while the next layer handles any business logic and interacts with a database (DAO) layer.

Comment: I just put everything in one function for example simplicity. I'm using daos. Well it's usually 1/2 or even 2/3 of the time is consumed by the getconnection call. So on a virtual machine I set up for this it usually takes 150ms for the whole request and around 90ms are spent on getconnection. The other 60s on the actual queries. When I use something like pgadmin one query takes about 40-60ms.

Comment: 1/2 or 2/3 of the time on the database interaction doesn't seem unusual to me - database interaction is often going to be the most expensive part of the solution.  150ms for a response against a RESTful API that is hitting a database doesn't seem that out of line.

Comment: Really? I mean I could understand a complex query taking that much time, but merely fetching a database connection from a connectiin pool?

Comment: absolutely - that's the wildcard...   if you are dealing with a larger volume of data and a more complex query, that would be in-line with expectations.  if this is a simple query against limited data, that would seem a little excessive.  i would start with taking the "restful" concept out of the equation.  how long does this take if your were using a basic command-line type of execution?  my experience is that the most basic "hello world" response that doesn't depend on a database or other i/o would take about 5ms.

Comment: Well yeah sure, but still. Also how does the volume of data in a DB matter at all when you fetch a connection from a connection pool? Shouldn't establishing a connection to a DB take the same time regardless of database size?